# How to get value of a custom attibute inside a <option> tag using JAVASCRIPT

Tags: javascript, html

My dropdown has a custom attributes and what I want to happen is to display the custom attributes value in a label tag.

Here is a code snippet:

```js
function setDesignation(d){
  var designation = d.getAttribute("data-designation");
  if(designation != null){
   document.getElementById('designation').innerHTML = designation;
  }else{
   document.getElementById('designation').innerHTML = 'Name';
  }
  //alert(d.getAttribute("data-designation"));
}
```

```html
<div>
    <select onchange="setDesignation(this)">
        <option value="1" data-designation="President">Mathew</option>
        <option value="2" data-designation="CEO">Mark</option>
        <option value="3" data-designation="Manager">Luke</option>\
        <option value="4" data-designation="">John</option>
    </select>
</div>

<div>
    <label id="designation">Designation</label>
</div>
```

The problem is that I can't get the value of the custom attributes which is the *"data-designation"*. I tried to put it in an alert() method to see the value and it says *"null"*. Even I remove the if else statement it still returns null. I don't know what wrong with the code so please help me.

I tried to find solution but all that I found are jQuery. I'm not good in jQuery so I would like a PURE JAVASCIPT solution.

P.S. if your solution is to store it in the value attribute then thats not what I'm looking for.

Comment: `this` is the select element not the selected option!

Comment: yes that make sense. anyway @Jonas W provided the answer i'm looking for. thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You dont want the selects data attribute, you want the selected options data attribute:

```
var designation = d.options[d.selectedIndex].getAttribute("data-designation");
```

Answer (score 1):

'this' here refers to the select and not the option.
You may want to try this instead:

```
function setDesignation(d){
  var designation = d.selectedOptions[0].getAttribute('data-designation');
  if(designation != null){
    document.getElementById('designation').innerHTML = designation;
  }else{
    document.getElementById('designation').innerHTML = 'Name';
  }
}
```

Hope this will help.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```js
 function setDesignation(d) {
            var designation = d.options[d.selectedIndex].getAttribute("data-designation");
            if (designation != "") {
                document.getElementById('designation').innerHTML = designation;
            } else {
                document.getElementById('designation').innerHTML = 'Name';
            }
        }
```

```html
<div>
        <select onchange="setDesignation(this)">
            <option value="1" data-designation="President">Mathew</option>
            <option value="2" data-designation="CEO">Mark</option>
            <option value="3" data-designation="Manager">Luke</option>\
            <option value="4" data-designation="">John</option>
        </select>
    </div>
    <div>
        <label id="designation">Designation</label>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to pass the option which is `this.options[this.selectedIndex]`:

```js
function setDesignation(d){
  var designation = d.getAttribute("data-designation");
  if(designation != null){
   document.getElementById('designation').innerHTML = designation;
  }else{
   document.getElementById('designation').innerHTML = 'Name';
  }
  //alert(d.getAttribute("data-designation"));
}
```

```html
<div>
    <select onchange="setDesignation(this.options[this.selectedIndex])">
        <option value="1" data-designation="President">Mathew</option>
        <option value="2" data-designation="CEO">Mark</option>
        <option value="3" data-designation="Manager">Luke</option>\
        <option value="4" data-designation="">John</option>
    </select>
</div>

<div>
    <label id="designation">Designation</label>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to pick the selected option first before you get the option

```
function setDesignation(d){
    var selectedDesignation = d.options[d.selectedIndex];
    console.log(selectedDesignation);
    var designation = selectedDesignation.getAttribute("data-designation");
    console.log(designation);
    if(designation != ""){
          document.getElementById('designation').innerHTML = designation;
    }else{
          document.getElementById('designation').innerHTML = 'Name';
    }
    //alert(d.getAttribute("data-designation"));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This should be fine. Change the != null to != '' so it display "Name" when data-designation is blank.

```
<div>
    <select onchange="setDesignation(this)">
        <option value="1" data-designation="President">Mathew</option>
        <option value="2" data-designation="CEO">Mark</option>
        <option value="3" data-designation="Manager">Luke</option>
        <option value="4" data-designation="">John</option>
    </select>
</div>

<div>
    <label id="designation">Designation</label>
</div>

<script>
    function setDesignation(d){
        var designation = d.options[d.selectedIndex].getAttribute("data-designation");
        var label = document.getElementById('designation');
        if(designation != ''){
            label.innerHTML = designation;
        }else{
            label.innerHTML = 'Name';
        }
    }
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can access data attributes using jQuery `data()` method:

```
var designation = d.options[d.selectedIndex].data("designation");
```

https://api.jquery.com/data/ - Jquery data() reference